# Flush mount Light won't unscrew

Tags: light, stuck

I have a flush mount dome light in my kitchen that burnt out a while ago. When I try to unscrew the nipple and remove the dome, the threaded rod inside the light spins as well. I tried seeing if I could just unscrew the rod from its bracket at the top but no luck. Pulling down on it with some force seemed to loosen the glass ever so slightly but that's it. Any ideas? I'm considering just taping up a garbage bag and shattering the glass inside it so I can replace the whole fixture.

Comment: "I tried seeing if I could just unscrew the rod from its bracket at the top but no luck" what _did_ happen? If it did turn at all, but didn't come off when you thought it would, it could be that there's a fair bit of that threaded rod and you'll just have to keep turning for a while.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this is a _surface_ mount light.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the threaded rod turns with the cap it will unscrew from the top. The threaded rod might be long. If that's not happening I would try to immobilize the rod while unscrewing the cap.
It sounds as if you've been able to get at least a little space between the cap and the glass. Use a pair of needle nose pliers to hold the rod and keep it from rotating while unscrewing the cap.